# Laravel - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::users()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

This is my model `Ticket`, when I want to create a ticket, I get error:

> Call to undefined method
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::users()

I don't know how to get rid of it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tickets extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, "user_tickets");
    }

    public function user_ticket()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(user_ticket::class);
    }
}
```

I think the problem comes from the **BelongsTo** relation but I don't know how to correct it.

This is my pivot Model table that im using

````
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class user_ticket extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

     protected $filable=[
        'user_id',
        'tickets_id',
];
public function users()
{
    return $this->HasMany(User::class, 'id');
}
public function tickets()
{
    return $this->HasMany(Tickets::class, 'id');
}
} ```


And this is my User Model 

    ```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use Laravel\Jetstream\HasProfilePhoto;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'role_id',
    ];
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'two_factor_recovery_codes',
        'two_factor_secret',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'profile_photo_url',
        'role_id',
    ];

    public function tickets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tickets::class, 'id');
    }
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Role::class);
    }
    public function user_ticket()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(user_tickets::class);
    }
} ```

And this is where im Using it 



    ``` 
@extends('dashboard')
@section('contenu')
    <div class="creer">
        <a href="{{ route('tickets.create') }}"class="btn-creer">
            Créer un ticket
        </a>
    </div>
    @csrf
    <div class="small-header anim" style="--delay: .3s">Vos Tickets</div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <th></th>
            <th id="titre"><b>Titre</b></th>
            <th id="titre">Description</th>
            <th id="titre">Statut</th>
            <th id="titre">Date de creation </th>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

            @foreach ($tickets as $ticket)
                {{ dd($ticket->user_ticket()->users()) }}
                @if (Auth::id() == $ticket->user_id)
                @endif
                <tr ng-repeat="data in information | filter:search">
                    <td></td>
                    <td>{{ $ticket->Titre }}</td>
                    <td>
                        @if (strlen($ticket->Description) > 20)
                            {{ substr($ticket->Description, 0, 20) }}...
                        @else
                            {{ $ticket->Description }}
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ $ticket->Statut }}</td>

                    <td>{{ $ticket->created_at }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{ route('tickets.edit', $ticket->id) }}">
                            <span class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"
                                ng-click="editInfo(data)"><br><small>Modifier</small></span></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a onclick="return confirm('Voulez-vous supprimer votre ticket ?')"
                            href="{{ route('destroy', $ticket->id) }}">
                            <span class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"
                                ng-click="deleteInfo(data)"><br><small>Supprimer</small></span></a>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach


        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
@endsection
````

My goal is to show the ticket that an User did create to himself and the Admins. How can i show it using the Gate Method ?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... where is the code actually causing this error?

Comment: Please add where you are using the method and then the related model.

Comment: Because user_ticket is a belongToMany relation, you can't call ->users() on it, because it's a collection, not a single model, perhaps you used the wrong relation, if it's the case try to use the belongTo relation instead. Also since you have a users relation on Tickets, simply do `$ticket->users()`

Comment: So sir how can I only show the tickets that the User have created ?